# How do I declare Lists in Blazor MAUI App

Tags: .net, blazor

How do I declare Lists in Blazor MAUI App?, the below code gives error.
Blazor MAUI App giving Error with List.
I want to create a quiz app using question and answers.
Load questions ,answers into list. Random numbers can be increased from 1  to n.

```
@page "/"


<h1>Counter</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>


 <p>Question</p> 
 
<div>
    <div>@question</div>
</div>
 <br>

 <p>Answer</p> 


<div>
    <div>@answer</div>
</div>
  <br>
@code {
 
    private int number;
      private Question[] questions;

    questions = new[] {
        new Question { Id = 1, Question = "Capital of France", Answer = "Paris" },
         new Question { Id = 2, Question = "Capital of Japan", Answer = "Tokyo" }
     
    };

  private void IncrementCount()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = rand.Next(1, 3);


var question = from s in Questions
         where s.Id == number
         select s.Question;


var answer = from s in Questions
         where s.Id == number
         select s.answer;
        
}
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? When is the assignment for `questions` supposed to run?